# How to get the user logged in in community page?

Tags: apex, community, page-layout, user-management, user-record

I need get the **user id logged** in a web page community site.com (not is a VisualForcePage) in this page I need the user id and others user's fields.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wt8dm.png]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can get it from the component or client side you need to query the information from server side with all the fields you want and pass it back to the lightning component.

Below syntax can be used as a starter in apex to get user id

```
UserInfo.getUserId()
```

Comment: Thanks, 
where is the better place to allocate this code?

Comment: Run it server side in your apex controller

Comment: No, no, this page it's not a visual force page, this page don't have direct relationship with the Controllers at least I don't know how this can be possible, this is in Community - Generator - All communities it's only a visual layer . . .